# Socket.io and requirejs dependency issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, requirejs, ace-editor

I have this legacy express project with two servers. I have this two client files:

```js
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '/js'
, paths: {
    "jquery": "lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min",
    "socket.io" : "lib/socket/socket.io"
  }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'socket.io'],
function   ($, io) {

  console.log(io);
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  [....]
```

And this:

```js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/js/lib'
  , paths: {
    "ace": "ace/lib/ace"
    , "bcsocket": "/channel/bcsocket"
    , "shareJS": "sharejs/share"
    , "sharejs_ace": "sharejs/ace"
    , "ace_java": "ace/mode/java"
    , "jquery": "jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min"
    , "socket.io": "socket/socket.io"
 }
 , shim: {
   "bcsocket": {
      exports: "BCSocket"
    }
    , "shareJS": {
     exports: "sharejs"
     , deps: ["bcsocket"]
  }
  , "sharejs_ace": {
     deps: ["ace/ace", "shareJS"]
  }
  , "ace_java": {
     deps: ['ace/ace']
  }
}
});

requirejs(['ace/ace', 'shareJS', 'bcsocket', 'sharejs_ace','jquery', 'socket.io'],
   function(ace, sharejs) {
      var editor = ace.edit('editor');
      editor.setTheme('ace/theme/twilight');
      editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/java');

      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

      console.log(socket)

      socket.emit('hi');

      [....]
```

The thing is: I can't access the variable **io** from the second file, only on the first. And even if I manage to join all the dependencies and files in just one, the socket.io stuff stops working.

This dependencies are in someway conflicting and I have no idea on what do to.

Here's my package.json:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "jade": "*",
    "share": "^0.6.3",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
    "connect": "*"
  },
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem:

```
requirejs([‘ace/ace’, ‘shareJS’, ‘bcsocket’, ‘sharejs_ace’,’jquery’, ‘socket.io’],
   function(ace, sharejs, io) {
```

And it was passing a **bcsocket** variable to io

So when I changed to

```
requirejs([‘ace/ace’, ‘shareJS’, ‘socket.io’, ‘bcsocket’, ‘sharejs_ace’,’jquery’],
   function(ace, sharejs, io) {
```

Then it passed socket.io variable to io.

It was just a problem with the order.